# Compile/PreCache Blade Templates

Tags: php, laravel, templates, caching, laravel-blade

From what I understand when using blade templates, the first time a user requests a page, blade will compile the template and create a cached version in a raw php format and from that point forward will render that page via the cache.

While this is nice, I was wondering if there is a way to precompile templates to the cache before a user hits the page. This allows someone to use a PHP linter on the cached files to see if there are any issues before hand.

Comment: What's the use case of using PHP lint on the cached files before hand?

Comment: Have a automated system hit the page.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois check for php errors. I've had issues with syntax errors creeping through in large applications. It's very time consuming to hit 1000+ pages via human testing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BDD or simple PHP script to simulate real visitors, so Laravel could create cached views for you.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't use it myself before, but a possible way could be using the BladeCompiler to manually compile the pages before entering them.

```
Blade::compile(string $path = null);
```

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.html#method_compile

Found another person using the compileString method.